# Mixin: Add property dynamically

Tags: css, sass, scss-mixins

Using Mixin, I want to determine a value between two entries and add it to a specific property.
Here is a dummy example:

```
@mixin min($property, $min1, $min2) {
  @if ($min1 > $min2) {
    $property: $min2;
  }
  @else {
    $property: $min1;
  }
}

.test {
  @include min(width, 11px, 13px);
}

.test1 {
  @include min(background-size, 30px, 13px);
}

.test2 {
  @include min(height, 8px, 50px);
}
```

I would like to have the ouput:

> width: 11px;
>
> background-size: 13px;
>
> height: 8px;

The problem is that `$property: $min1;` sets `min1` value to `property` and I would like to return a literal.

How can I do that using mixin ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there. You must use [interpolation](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/interpolation) on the `$property` variable:

```
@mixin min($property, $min1, $min2) {
  @if ($min1 > $min2) {
    #{$property}: $min2;
  }
  @else {
    #{$property}: $min1;
  }
}
```